# How to thicken shape infill in Processing?

Tags: graphics, 3d, processing, visualization

## Problem

**NOTE: I cannot use box()**

I'm trying to generate a 3D shape from **only** 4 points in processing. The problem I'm having is that when I use createShape(), Processing fills the shape with a 2D plane, and I cannot find anyway to "thicken" it:

[image]

---

## What I've tried

As a work around, I'm "thickening" the shape using lines instead of createShape(). The results from this produce this:

[image]

The only problem with this is that lighting no longer works as stroke doesn't change according to the lighting, so you cannot perceive the shape's depth.

---

## Is there anyway to produce the desired result and preserve lighting?

```
import peasy.*;

PeasyCam camera;

void setup() {
  size(800, 800, P3D);

  camera = new PeasyCam(this, 50, 0, 0, 100);
  camera.reset();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  lights();
  
  //createShapeMethod();
  //lineMethod();
  
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  plotPoint(0, 0, 0);
  plotPoint(100, 0, 0);
  plotPoint(100, 0, -100);
  plotPoint(0, 0, -100);
  
}


void beginShapeMethod() {
  stroke(255);
  fill(color(255,0,0));
  beginShape();
  vertex(0, 0, 0);
  vertex(100, 0, 0);
  vertex(100, 0, -100);
  vertex(0, 0, -100);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

void lineMethod() {
  strokeWeight(40);
  stroke(color(255,0,0));
  int f = 100;
  for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    line(
      i, 0, 0,
      i, 0, -100
    );
  }

}


void plotPoint(int x, int y, int z) {
  translate(x,y,z);
  sphere(5);
  translate(-x,-y,-z);
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're strictly working in 2D right now. Have you read the [P3D introduction](https://processing.org/tutorials/p3d/)?

Comment: @laancelot No, this is in 3D.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think it's a 2D shape drawn using a 3D renderer.

Comment: Oh yes then I would agree with you, however this was intentional to just simplify the example. @laancelot